Unable to install IvyDE in Eclipse
I'm working on a Java project in Eclipse IDE 4.32.0.20240606-0749. I'm trying to install IvyDE but I'm encountering some issues.
Here's what I've done so far:
I tried to add IvyDE Managed Dependencies through the Java Build Path in my project properties, but the option was not available.
I checked if IvyDE was installed through the Eclipse Marketplace, but it wasn't.
I tried to install IvyDE through the Eclipse Marketplace, but I encountered an error saying "No repository found at https://www.apache.org/dist/ant/ivyde/updatesite."
I tried to add the IvyDE update site manually using the URL http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/update, but I encountered an error saying "Could not find http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/update."
I'm not sure what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you look at the IvyDE site https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/ you will see the project has been shutdown (archived). The archive has an update site https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/ivyde/updatesite/ but since this is no longer maintained it may not work on current versions of Eclipse.

So maybe I should choose an old version of eclipse and may worked? I really need to make it work for my old project I've got in my hands.

Manually add an update site and point it to https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/ivyde/updatesite/
